# Building react native app fails on android licenses

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, android-studio, build

I'm diving into react native world for first time and I'm trying to setup a Windows dev environment from scratch following [this article](https://shift.infinite.red/getting-started-with-react-native-development-on-windows-90d85a72ae65). Everything is ok until I try running `react-native run-android`. I've already accepted all licences with `sdkmanager --licenses` but I still get licences errors:

```
> Configure project :app
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3 in C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3 not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 27 in C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 27 not accepted.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
     platforms;android-27 Android SDK Platform 27
     build-tools;27.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3
  To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
```

Then I found [this comment](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/527#issuecomment-320194242) where a user suggests the following command: `$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;26.0.1" "platforms;android-26"`. I executed it as `sdkmanager.bat "platforms;android-27" "build-tools;27.0.3"` to match the versions in my env and the manager did downloaded new licences, but the errors stays.

I don't know how to accept those licences above. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this command `yes | sdkmanager --licenses`

or you can use this command  for mac `yes | sudo ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses`

or for windows: `cmd.exe ""/K"%LocalAppData%\Android\sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat --licenses"`

Comment: `sdkmanager --licences` says that there is no licence to accept.

Comment: you need to double-check $ANDROID_HOME PATH  .try to echo ANDROID_HOME by typing in terminal `echo $ANDROID_HOME`, 
then  try this  yes | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses

Comment: I'm telling you, its always gives me **"All SDK package licenses accepted."**

Answer (score 0):

Open Android Studio->SDK Manager then select Android 8.1 (Oreo) Press OK then accept the license and install

Comment: I have all SDKs from 4.4 to 10.0 already installed in my Android Studio.

Comment: Then please try uninstall one package and reinstall it

Answer (score 0):

For me:

- The ANDROID_HOME value is (for me) D:\Android, and the CLI adds automatically 'platform-tools' at the end oh the path
- In the licenses folders, I have deleted all of them and ran *yes | sdkmanager --licenses*
- I copied the licenses folder into platform-tools directory
- I check once again if the values of JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_HOME are correct. I had to reboot my computer to apply this changes

If you have a REGEX error at start (like with Expo), just go into node_modules\metro-config\src\defaults\blacklist.js and change the sharedBlacklist's first line by :

```
*/node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,*
```

The CLI squeals because the first \ is missing into each brackets.

In the CLI :

I use Nox Player to run the project.

- Launch Nox Player
- *adb connect 127.0.0.1:62001*
- *adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081*
- *react-native run-android*

That works for me.